# How to start a Backgroundworker ByRef

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker, byref

I wanted to assign a custom name to a backgroundworker so I created a custom class:

```
 Public Class NamedBKW
        Public BKW As BackgroundWorker
        Public Name As String
        Public Sub New(ByVal thisBKW As BackgroundWorker, ByVal thisName As String)
            BKW = thisBKW
            Name = thisName
        End Sub
    End Class
```

I have a list of these NamedBKWs that I'd like to start one at a time by iterating through a loop.  The list is built when the program starts.

```
Friend Sub StartService()
[...]

BuildLists()

For x As Integer = 0 To ListOfBKWs.Count - 1
                StartThisThread(ListOfBKWs(x).BKW, ListOfBKWs(x).Name)
                Thread.Sleep(3000)
            Next
End Sub

Public Sub BuildLists()
[...]
 ' List of BKWs:
            ' Note that the order listed here will determine the order they are started.
            ListOfBKWs = New List(Of NamedBKW)
            ListOfBKWs.Add(New NamedBKW(ScheduleCheckerBKW, "ScheduleChecker"))
            ListOfBKWs.Add(New NamedBKW(BackupStage5BKW, "Stage 5"))
            ListOfBKWs.Add(New NamedBKW(BackupStage4BKW, "Stage 4"))
            ListOfBKWs.Add(New NamedBKW(BackupStage3BKW, "Stage 3"))
            ListOfBKWs.Add(New NamedBKW(BackupStage2BKW, "Stage 2"))
            ListOfBKWs.Add(New NamedBKW(BackupStage1BKW, "Stage 1"))
            ListOfBKWs.Add(New NamedBKW(DeleteOldFilesBKW, "DeleteOldFiles"))
            ListOfBKWs.Add(New NamedBKW(FixerBKW, "Fixer"))
            ListOfBKWs.Add(New NamedBKW(ThreadCheckerBKW, "ThreadChecker"))
End Sub

Public Sub StartThisThread(ByRef thisBKW As BackgroundWorker, ByVal thisName As String)
            NPC.WriteToConsoleAndLog("MAIN: Starting " & thisName & " thread...")
            thisBKW = New BackgroundWorker
            thisBKW.WorkerReportsProgress = True
            thisBKW.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
            thisBKW.RunWorkerAsync()
End Sub
```

But for some reason this does not work.  The console/log prints the message that it is starting each thread, but the threads don't actually start.  What am I doing wrong?

All of the Backgroundworkers are declared in the main class, like this:

`Friend WithEvents BackupStage1BKW As New BackgroundWorker`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declarations to create the background worker objects like this:

```
Friend WithEvents BackupStage1BKW As New BackgroundWorker
```

However, nothing in what you've shown indicates these workers actually do anything. If there is a method to handle the `DoWork` event for each worker that is wired up as part of the `WithEvents` declaration, we can't see it.

I'll pretend for a moment these methods do exist and are correctly subscribed to the events. In that case we come to the next issue. This line over-writes the declared objects:

```
 thisBKW = New BackgroundWorker
```

You now have *brand new objects*, and any event handler that was there before no longer applies.

You really don't want that line, and you *don't want* `ByRef` here. Remember, *ByVal still passes references!* The only difference is it passes a *copy* of the reference, and it turns out that's exactly what you need most of the time.

Comment: Indeed, these two edits resolved the issue.  I've developed a habit of declaring objects as new before using them in order to either make sure there is an instance of the object, or to make sure they're not storing anything from a previous part of their lifecycle.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @ChargersFan, *"I've developed a habit of declaring objects as new"*. No you haven't. There's no such thing as declaring an object, new or otherwise. You declare a variable, you create an object and you assign the object to the variable. If you have developed a habit, it is of creating new objects and assigning them to the declared variables before using them. The habit you should be developing is thinking about whether you actually need a new object at that point. If the variable was declared automatically due to adding a control/component in the designer, you definitely don't.